# how to get available network list in android?

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

Hi I am beginner to Android.I want get available network list using `com.android.phone.NetworkSetting`.For that, I tried to get the network list by call this package, when I click a scan button.The output is automatically call the android core Network Settings.Its Start automatically search the available networks and list outed available networks, Instead of I want get the same available network list in my List View.So please guide me to retrieve the network name and details from this package.

```
scanbtnOnclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.internal.phone");
            intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I also accept another method to retrieve this same concept.

Answer (score -1):

use wifimanager API to manage all the wi-fi connections.

```
WifiManager mainWifiObj;

mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);`

public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

    }
}

WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

You can put scan results into string variable and use it.

```
List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
String data = wifiScanList.get(0).toString();
```

hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's for wifi, but i am asking about cellular networ.